# Getting the URL of an attachment in Discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am trying to get the URL of the file that the user attaches so I can use it later on in my code however I'm not too sure on how to go about doing so.

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def readURL(ctx, url):
    # Do something
```

**References:**

- [discord.ext.commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=ctx)
- [Attachment.url](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Attachment.url)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, it would go like this:

```py
@client.command() # context is automatically passed in rewrite
async def readURL(ctx):
    attachment = ctx.message.attachments[0] # gets first attachment that user
                                            # sent along with command
    print(attachment.url)
```

---

**References:**

- [`Attachment.url`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Attachment.url)
- [`Message.attachments`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.attachments)

Comment: Worked! Thanks, picked as solution :)

Comment: Great! Happy coding :')