# Check if user send a .mp4 file with specified name to bot's Dm

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I need to check if user sends a .mp4 file with specified name (for example: pizza), and if that's true, bot send a message. Is there's a way i can do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the URL of an attachment in Discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61898621/getting-the-url-of-an-attachment-in-discord-py)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem. It would be beneficial for you to read discords/python/bot documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There's a better way to do this that isn't addressed in the dupe. The file object contains an attribute [`filename`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Attachment.filename). You can then iterate over all the attachments and check for the file:

```py
for file in <your message object goes here>.attachments:
    if file.url == 'pizza.mp4':
        # do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ctx.message.attachments: #checks if there are any attachments
    for attachment in ctx.message.attachments: #checks all attachments if there are multiple
        if str(attachment) == "pizza.mp4": 
            print("found attachment!")
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this in your `on_message` event:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.guild is None and message.author != bot.user: # dm message
        try:
            file = message.attachments[0] # try getting the file
            if "pizza" in str(file.filename): # check if name is in the filename
                await ctx.send("message") # send message
            else:
                await ctx.send(f"pizza not found in {str(file.filename)}")
        except: # user did not send a file/attachment
            await ctx.send("no file sent")
```

Comment: Not working and no errors. Maybe i can somehow use `discord.Attachment.filename` attribute?

Comment: @enderport Yes, you can use the `filename` attribute. I've edited my answer to reflect this change.

Comment: Credit also to @EricJin for pointing the `filename` attribute out.